# How to develop a mobile applications that can connect to a Samsung Smart TV app?

Tags: android, web-applications, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to make a Smart TV application that can communicate with a mobile application, preferable android. I have tried this tutorials from Samsung Smart TV developers forum: 
http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00024/index.html
Although it only explains how to find a Smart TV on the same network for android. Not how to communicate with it. 
I have got the webbased Chrome version to work, although I cant use it on my phone because you have to run the browser in: --disable-web-security moode.

I have also tried Movl: https://connect.movl.com. But the api key that i got from them and one of the examples available does not work for me. Probably because I am located in Singapore (why, i dont know) but it works for the support staff at Movl and my friend back home in Sweden.

I want to know how I can connect a mobile application to a Smart TV application (also developed by me) and send information between them. Does anyone know how to do that?

Very grateful for answers

Answer (score 1):

[DIAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIscovery_And_Launch)

it is the protocol used by many leading companies to LAUNCH the activity on the smart tv FROM an android smart PHONE

I HOPE THIS WILL BE OF SOME HELP TO YOU

CHEERS

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use the N-Screen API. Specifically look into `webapis.nservice`
Tutorial here: [N-Service](http://developer.samsung.com/samsung-web-api/technical-docs/N-Service)